# turning off smooth scrolling in Outlook 2010

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-outlook-2007

I want to turn off smooth scrolling everywhere. That is, I want display updates such as the effect of <kbd>PgUp</kbd>/<kbd>PgDn</kbd> to happen in a single screen refresh, rather than one pixel line at a time.

I've mostly achieved this under Windows XP by turning off most display effects in the “System/Advanced/Performance” component of the Control Panel, and unchecking “Use smooth scrolling” in “Internet Options/Advanced/Browse”. Under Windows 7, the display effects are under “System/Advanced system settings/Advanced/Performance” and the IE setting is under “Network and Internet/Internet Options/Advanced”. This takes care of all but one Microsoft applications that I use, including Help and Word.

The one exception is Outlook 2007 or 2010, which still scrolls smoothly when I press <kbd>PgUp</kbd> or <kbd>PgDn</kbd> in a mail view or compose window. How can I turn it off there too?